# Correct way to store JSON into SQL database in React/Python(Django) app

Tags: python, reactjs, json, django, postgresql

So, I have, in my React application, a method that will generate a json with some settings and data, like this:

```
const generateJSON = async () => {
    const json = generateManualJSON(caseId);

    const data = {
        cdata: customData,
        settings: json,
    };

    try {
        const response = await Axios.post(`/manual/${caseId}/generate`, { manual_settings: JSON.stringify(data) });
        console.log('response.data', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        setError(arch, true, [error.message]);
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

and this will end up in this View  in my Django application:

```
class Manual(APIView):

    def transaction(self, case_id, action, request):
        user = request.user
        manual_settings = request.data['manual_settings']
        if (action == 'generate'):
            CaseAutomationStatusModel.objects.create(
                current_ind=True,
                case_id=case_id,
                created_by=user,
                modified_by=user,
                status_comment=manual_wire_settings
            )

    def post(self, request, case_id, action):
        try:
            self.transaction(case_id, action, request)
            return JsonResponse({
                'status': 200,
                'message': 'Success'
            })
        except Exception as err:
            print('*** API error', err)
```

We are using PostgreSQL as database.

The purpose of this is that we have a few jobs that run with nextflow and python running in paralel, and it this nextflow job will get this json in the database, and use it.

But the problem is, the way it is currently stored, probably due to lack of escape characters, the database string input (which is the one we saved in the react/python project) is breaking up into many different inputs.

So, to solve that issue, what would be the best way to store this data?
I will not be sorting or doing anything else with it besides storing it to be readed by the other job.

Comment: Can you give an example of this _"the database string input (which is the one we saved in the react/python project) is breaking up into many different inputs."_